# How to create a Swift model for JSON

Tags: json, swift, nscoding

```
{"dataList":{"1547795650562": {
        "c0a8007b-6759-111d-8167-59e8dabe0086": {
          "recordDate": 1547795650562,
          "resultValue": "160",
          "vitalParameter": {
            "uom": {
              "code": "KG",
              "name": "KG",
              "id": "c0a8007b-6759-111d-8167-59e76204007f"
            },
            "resultType": {
              "code": "VSRTNUMERIC",
              "name": "Numeric",
              "id": "20cf4756-40b0-4cc1-acb5-861765370a41"
            },
            "code": "29463-7",
            "name": "Weight",
            "id": "c0a8007b-6759-111d-8167-59e8dabe0086"
          },
          "id": "c0a8007b-6855-1d16-8168-5fd18fa301b7"
        }}
}}
```

getting 1547795650562 and c0a8007b-6759-111d-8167-59e8dabe0086 as class names. But I dont want like this;

```
class DataList : NSObject, NSCoding{
    var 1547795650562 : 1547795650562!
}

class 1547795650562 : NSObject, NSCoding{
    var c0a8007b6759111d816759e8dabe0086 : VitalParameter!
}
```

But the problem here is, 1547795650562 and c0a8007b-6759-111d-8167-59e8dabe0086 cannot be hard coded because they may change.

c0a8007b-6759-111d-8167-59e8dabe0086 is dynamic id and 1547795650562 is recordDate. Inner object is repetitive.

But I have to map as the keys are of recordDate and id respectively.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Also, what all data do you need from this JSON?

Comment: ys. But getting 1547795650562 and c0a8007b-6759-111d-8167-59e8dabe0086 as class names. But I have to map as the keys are of recordDate and id respectively. Thanks

Comment: Could not understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: Can you add some code which give you class and how you are reading this JSON? base don that we can help you in your Modal creation issue.

Comment: class DataList : NSObject, NSCoding{

 var 1547795650562 : 1547795650562!

Comment: class 1547795650562 : NSObject, NSCoding{

 var c0a8007b6759111d816759e8dabe0086 : VitalParameter!

Comment: But the problem here is , 1547795650562 and c0a8007b-6759-111d-8167-59e8dabe0086 cannot be hard coded because they may change

Comment: c0a8007b-6759-111d-8167-59e8dabe0086 is dynamic id and 1547795650562 is recordDate. Inner object is repeatative

Comment: who is managing backend?

Comment: I see a major design problem with this JSON, those dynamic ids must be values, not keys. You can maybe solve this by using reflection or other methods but really this is a backend problem. Those ids must be wrapped in static named keys. Tell your backend guys to fix it, this is not the app developers problem.

Comment: This question is highly downvoted, abandoned, and has left some questions unanswered. On that basis I think it should be closed. "Lacks Clarity" is probably recommended - it isn't going to get fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`Codable`** instead of `NSCoding` to parse your JSON data.

**Models:**

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let dataList: [String:[String:Record]]
}

struct Record: Codable {
    let recordDate: Int
    let resultValue: String
    let vitalParameter: VitalParameter
    let id: String
}

struct VitalParameter: Codable {
    let uom, resultType: ResultType
    let code, name, id: String
}

struct ResultType: Codable {
    let code, name, id: String
}
```

**Parse** the JSON data using above models like,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Note**: You can use https://app.quicktype.io to get the models from your JSON instantly. Make the changes as per your requirement and you're good to go.

Comment: But the problem here is , 1547795650562 and c0a8007b-6759-111d-8167-59e8dabe0086 cannot be hard coded because they may change

Comment: c0a8007b-6759-111d-8167-59e8dabe0086 is dynamic id and 1547795650562 is recordDate. Inner object is repeatative

Comment: Updated the models as per requirement,

Comment: how to parse as one object's id as its key

Comment: What do you mean by "parse as one object's id as its key"? Give an example.